# angular material design with phonegap build doesn't seems to be working in android version below 4.4

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, angular-material

Following are my html, css and js file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.gitcdn.xyz/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.css">

    </head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as appCtrl">
  <md-grid-list
        md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="6"
        md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="2:2"
        md-gutter="12px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px" >

    <md-grid-tile class="gray"
        md-rowspan="3" md-colspan="2" md-colspan-sm="1">
      <md-grid-tile-footer>
        <h3>#1: (3r x 2c)</h3>
      </md-grid-tile-footer>
    </md-grid-tile>

    <md-grid-tile class="green">
      <md-grid-tile-footer>
        <h3>#2: (1r x 1c)</h3>
      </md-grid-tile-footer>
    </md-grid-tile>

    <md-grid-tile class="yellow">
      <md-grid-tile-footer>
        <h3>#3: (1r x 1c)</h3>
      </md-grid-tile-footer>
    </md-grid-tile>

    <md-grid-tile class="blue"
        md-rowspan="2">
      <md-grid-tile-footer>
        <h3>#4: (2r x 1c)</h3>
      </md-grid-tile-footer>
    </md-grid-tile>

    <md-grid-tile class="red"
        md-rowspan="2" md-colspan="2" md-colspan-sm="1">
      <md-grid-tile-footer>
        <h3>#5: (2r x 2c)</h3>
      </md-grid-tile-footer>
    </md-grid-tile>

    <md-grid-tile class="green"
        md-rowspan="2" >
      <md-grid-tile-footer>
        <h3>#6: (2r x 1c)</h3>
      </md-grid-tile-footer>
    </md-grid-tile>

  </md-grid-list>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.xyz/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
</html>
```

And custom.css:

```
.gridListdemoBasicUsage md-grid-list {
  margin: 8px; }
.gridListdemoBasicUsage .gray {
  background: #f5f5f5; }
.gridListdemoBasicUsage .green {
  background: #b9f6ca; }
.gridListdemoBasicUsage .yellow {
  background: #ffff8d; }
.gridListdemoBasicUsage .blue {
  background: #84ffff; }
.gridListdemoBasicUsage .purple {
  background: #b388ff; }
.gridListdemoBasicUsage .red {
  background: #ff8a80; }
.gridListdemoBasicUsage md-grid-tile {
  transition: all 400ms ease-out 50ms; }
```

And custom.js:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

And after creating the build through cordova and install the apk on android phone below 4.4, the grid title is not working. Only we can see the blank screen. But its working in android version 4.4 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think android below `4.4` is not currently supported. There are some [issues](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1775) about it.

An accepted recommendation is to use **crosswalk** project, which replaces the default webview with a chromium version. We've tested in our app (just in development phase) and it seems to be working pretty well.

See https://crosswalk-project.org

Hope it helps

Comment: i integrated the the crosswalk plugin, and its seems to working in android version below 4.4. But the content looks small. When we use the same apk to android version 4, we get the same content. Without the crosswalk plugin, the app was working perfectly in android 4.4. Is there any solution for this? ie, the app should work based on the android version.

Comment: So if I've understood you correctly, now with crosswalk is working fine but the grid content is looking smaller? This would require more investigation...I don't know what could cause this behaviour.

Comment: The apk without crosswalk plugin works perfectly in android 4.4 and above. Now I added crosswalk plugin to incorporate the app in android version below 4.4. And its working perfectly. I tried the shared mode build. When i install the shared mode build in android version above 4.4, its asking for crosswalk library. Is there anyway to discard this library in android vesrion above 4.4 because the app has no issue in those versions.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know if this is posible.I'll deep into this and let you know if I find a way to do that.

Comment: if get any result, please let me know